# Javascript Print function - file name

Tags: javascript, printing

I am using the window.print() function in javaScript to print a page which is executed from a button onClick.

```
<input type="submit" value="Print" class="register-button" onClick="window.print()"/>
```

In the popup the default filename is the name of the website found it the  tags in the header.

Is there anyway I can set a parameter in the function so the default save filename is what ever I want it to be?

Cheers.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

`onClick="document.title = 'My new title';window.print();"`

You can try it here:

```html
    <html>
    <head>
    <title>My title</title>
    </head>
    <body>
    <button onClick="document.title = 'My new title';window.print();">Try it</button>
    <p id="demo"></p>
    </body>
    </html>
```

Comment: Hey LAS_VEGAS. That didn't quite work but put it into a function and called that instead and it worked fine!! Although it does change the name at the top of the page but it's not much of a worry to me. function driverprint(){
   document.title = "Sam";
   window.print();
   
  }

Comment: You can try to change back: `driverprint(){ document.title = "Sam"; window.print(); document.title = "LAS_VEGAS";}`

Comment: This does work in Google Chrome but not in Firefox 68.0.1

Comment: @Phil I just tested on Firefox and it is working for me

Comment: @Caner If i run the code snippet, it does not work for me in Firefox 68.0.1 :( And I tried it in my own implementation without success.

Comment: @Phil maybe you can post a question on SO, it works for me on 68.0.2 on mac

Answer (score 1):

According to MDC, `window.print()` has no parameters to control anything.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/window.print

Comment: Cheers SHiNKiROU for looking into. I managed to hack around the issue but will need to look into a different approach.