# How to create a custom file name for a file while saving the print page?

Tags: javascript, asp.net

Here i am printing a page through window.print() event and before printing i need to save this page for that i need to hardcore a file name in this event.

```
   <a href="_javascript:window.print()">
    <img class="noPrint" src="Images/Print_icon.png" border="0"></a>
```

Any suggestion?

Comment: Well. [What have you tried](http://mattgemmell.com/2008/12/08/what-have-you-tried/)

Comment: i have tried like this one http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4467578/javascript-print-function-file-name

Comment: Seems IE11 "helpfully" appends the URL to your title, so the filename winds up being whatever the last segment of your URL is. DOH!

Answer (score 27, accepted):

You can change the title via [`document.title`](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/prop_doc_title.asp):

```
<a href="someRealUrl" onclick="document.title='My new title'; window.print(); return false;"><img class="noPrint" src="Images/Print_icon.png" border="0"></a>
```

Comment: I dont have a print preview page.. So saving the page using "Microsoft xps document writer" . And while saving it, it needs to take a custom file name by default

Comment: @Rooney: But it takes the document's title by default and that's what you're changing via `document.title`. So i don't understand your comment.

Comment: this is what it is taking by default  *.xps

Comment: @Rooney: I don't think that it's possible to change the defaults of the Microsoft xps document writer via javascript, at least i don't know a way.

Comment: If you notice, the `document.title` changes the title of the webpage as well.

Answer (score 9):

See:

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowEventHandlers/onbeforeprint
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowEventHandlers/onafterprint

> The beforeprint and afterprint events allow pages to change their content before printing starts (perhaps to remove a banner, for example) and then revert those changes after printing has completed. In general, you should prefer the use of a @media print CSS at-rule, but it may be necessary to use these events in some cases.

The solution to your problem would be to change `document.title` in `beforeprint` event handler and revert to its original value in `afterprint` event handler.

Answer (score 5):

```
onClick="document.title = "My new title";window.print();"
```

Answer (score 3):

I know this is an old thread, but just to add an example to Lukasz Prus answer, you can use `document.title` (as in the accepted answer) whith the following lines (changes page title to the desired one before printing, and back to original after that):

```
window.addEventListener("beforeprint", (event) => {
  document.title='My desired save filename';
});

window.addEventListener("afterprint", (event) => {
  document.title='The original page title';
});
```