# period removed from filename when printing with jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-chrome

I've been tasked with coming up with a solution for dynamically printing a specific part of the page in an existing application. I'm getting information by finding certain sections of the page based on class tags and then printing that section with the following.

```
function PrintElem(element,title) {
  var data = $(element).html();
  var mywindow = window.open('', title, 'height=800,width=1000');
  mywindow.document.write('<html><head><title>' + title + '</title>');  
  mywindow.document.write('</head><body >');
  mywindow.document.write(data);
  mywindow.document.write('</body></html>');
  mywindow.print();
  mywindow.close();
  return true;                
}
```

The problem occurs with the title variable. The title is used for the window thats opened and the printed file name and is based on a company document type, customer, part number and part number revision. On a part I've been testing the title variable shows as RTR_COMPANY_3900801597.1_A the problem occurs when its printed. Once the print dialog opens it drops the .1_A (in chrome, edge, IE, firefox) and so far I haven't found or thought of a way to get around this. Other thoughts are that it must be able to work in Chrome (used company wide). Any thoughts?

Comment: You can't control what the OS does in those dialogs. Sounds like you are on Windows, and it really likes file extensions. You might try padding it with another "dummy" extension or just adding another ending period, but I think that may cause you issues.

Comment: @Kyle It works just fine for me? https://i.snag.gy/h3IaKN.jpg

Comment: It seems like adding a dummy file name (title + ".pdf") seems to have fixed it. Thank mrunion for that idea.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I get you right, you're using a dot in a way that your SO could get confused with a file extension (.1_A). Can you try setting a file extension after the name like

```
mywindow.document.write('<html><head><title>' + title + '.pdf</title>');
```

Aso, check [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4467618/1358777)

Comment: Thanks, didn't even think of that(its been a long day). After adding the .pdf works like a charm.