# How can I set the default filename for the Chrome print dialog from within an iframe?

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-chrome, iframe

I'm working on a project where my part of the project is a dashboard within an iframe. I have a request to make *just* the iframe I'm working on exportable as a PDF (that is, only show the iframe contents and not the wrapper stuff around it). I've gotten that to work using some jQuery, but 
I'm now stumped at setting a default filename for saving as PDF. [This SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4467618/3854235) was helpful (setting document.title works when the page is *not* in an iframe), but it doesn't work when the export button is clicked when it is in the iframe view. Here's an example of what I've tried:

```
$('#export-button').click(function() {
    $('#iframe-contents').show();
    document.title = 'default_filename';
    window.print();
});
```

Does anyone know how to set the default filename in the Chrome print dialog when calling on `window.print()` from within an iframe?

Comment: Why do you need a filename in a print dialog? Windows (not sure about other OS) doesn't even show a filename in a print dialog

Comment: For a better customer experience. When people export my report as a PDF, I want the default filename to include the report number and the date because the report contents will change over time. In Mac OS X (and I assume on other OSes) Chrome sets the default filename to the document title. For example, if you try to print this page and save as PDF, Chrome on OS X sets the default filename to "javascript - How can I set the default filename for the Chrome print dialog from within an iframe_ - Stack Overflow.pdf".

Comment: `When people export my report` ... oh, I misread the `default filename for the Chrome print dialog` to mean you want a filename in the print dialog - didn't realise the question was about exporting to PDF

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Firefox does set the pdf name directly to the iframe's document's name, weird that chrome doesn't.

For a workaround, **if your iframe shares the same origin as your parent page**, you can use :

```
document.title = window.parent.document.title = "yourTitle";
```

If they don't share the same origin, <s>you're stuck</s>.

Actually there is an hack, even for cross-origin frames involving `window.open()`, hence not working in sand-boxed iframes without 'allow-popups' permission.

```
function renameIframedPrint(title) {
  var title = "myFile";
  try {
    // same-origin frame
    document.title = window.parent.document.title = title;
    print();
  } catch (e) { // cross-origin frame

    // we could instead grab the current content of the page
    // but for the demo, location.href will do
    var p = window.open(location.href);
    p.onload = function() {
      // no more frame so we don't care ;-)
      p.document.title = "myFile";
      // a bit more hack to close the popup once printed...
      function closePopup() {
        p.close();
      }
      if ('onafterprint' in p) {
        // FF and IE
        p.onafterprint = closePopup
      } else {
        // webkit don't support onafterprint
        var mediaQueryList = p.matchMedia('print');
        mediaQueryList.addListener(mqlListener);

        function mqlListener(mql) {
          if (!mql.matches) {
            closePopup();
            mediaQueryList.removeListener(mqlListener);
          }
        }
      }
    }
    // we're ready
    p.print();
  };
}
```

[External Live Demo](http://plnkr.co/edit/jVCfqLQQFROzTgXqmfVb?p=preview), since `open()` won't work in stack-snippet's sand-boxed iframe.