# setTimeout not working on production but it works fine on local enviroment

Tags: javascript, reactjs, settimeout

I had a react-app that is being used as a widget in Iframe. And there I had a report page for which we have an option to print that.

I am using this StackOverflow [solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42014507/how-can-i-set-the-default-filename-for-the-chrome-print-dialog-from-within-an-if) to use the print function. Additionally, I have just added a timeout function to let the page load API data first and then open the print function. This piece of code works very fine when tested in the local environment, that is, the print popup appears after 2.7 seconds (desired behavior) but in production, the print popup opens instantly (undesired behavior).

```
const onClickOfPrint = () => {
    var title = questionnaireQuestionsSuccessData.name;
    try {
      // same-origin frame
      document.title = window.parent.document.title = title; // to check if same origin
      // handlePrint();
    } catch (err) {
      // cross-origin frame
      var p = window.open(reportPageUrl);
      p.onload = function () {
        p.document.title = title;

        const closePopup = () => {
          p.close();
        };

        if ('onafterprint' in p) {
          // FF and IE
          p.onafterprint = closePopup;
        } else {
          // webkit don't support onafterprint
          var mediaQueryList = p.matchMedia('print');
          mediaQueryList.addEventListener('change', mqlListener);
          const mqlListener = (mql) => {
            if (!mql.matches) {
              closePopup();
              mediaQueryList.removeEventListener('change', mqlListener);
            }
          };
        }
      };
      setTimeout(() => {
            p.print();
          }, 2700);
    }
  };
```

Comment: you're the second person in 2 days that has used such a bizarre setInterval/setTimeout combination - why not just `callprint = setTimeout` ... then you don't have to clear the interval 300ms after it first triggers!! ... anyway - relying on timeout for a page to load will always be intermittent

Comment: which "timeout" do you expect the "print dialog" to "wait" for?

Comment: @JaromandaX sorry mistakenly I wrote the wrong setTimeout there. I have edited it now, can you please check again

Comment: yes, so you're still relying on the page being ready to print after 2.7 seconds ... but that's not your question ... you ask why "the print dialogue is not waiting for the timeout to finish" ... I don't understand ... are you saying the print dialogue appears before 2.7 seconds has elapsed?

Comment: @JaromandaX in development, the print popup appears after 2.7 seconds (desired behavior) but in production, the print popup opens instantly (undesired behavior).

Comment: your code must be different in production :p nothing can short-circuit a timeout